# Import registry file to registry using windows API

Tags: c++, c, windows, registry

I am trying to write some C/C++ code that will import a .reg file into the registry. The MSDN has functions for importing a file for specific keys but I want to import for example the entire HKCU hive.

Comment: "I want to import for example the entire HKCU hive" is a recipe for disaster.  Significant portions of the per-user registry take permanent values at the time of user profile creation and should not be overwritten.  You could talk about a backup and restore operation, but not "import".

Answer (score 3):

There is no Win32 API for importing a `.reg` file into the Registry <sup>1</sup>. You will have to parse the file yourself and translate the instructions into appropriate Registry API function calls as needed - `Reg(Open|Create)KeyEx()`, `RegSetValueEx()`, `RegDelete(Key|Value)()`, etc.

<sup>1: don't be confused by the existence of `RegLoadKey()`, `RegReplaceKey()`, and `RegRestoreKey()`.  They are intended for loading files created by `RegSaveKey/Ex()`, which are not text-based `.reg` files.</sup>

Otherwise, you can just use `ShellExecute/Ex()` or `CreateProcess()` to execute `regedit.exe /s <filename>` or [`reg.exe import <filename>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-import) with the path to the `.reg` file as a command-line parameter, letting `regedit`/`reg` handle the import for you.  This would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: There's also `reg.exe` with its `/import` switch, if you're going to spawn an external tool.  Notably `reg.exe` doesn't require admin rights unless the registry operations require them, whereas `regedit.exe` is marked to always elevate.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, I have updated my answer